# I have got a list of pairs how can i check whether the list contains a specific element or not.The list.contains function is always giving false

Tags: java, list, collections

I have created a pair class and list of objects of this class. how can i check whether the list contains a object or not

i have tried list.contains method

```
//the pair class

public static  class pair
{
    int x,y;
    public pair(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

//this line is always giving false as output

if (!l.contains(new pair(x-1,y)))
                count_1++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, objects in Java are only equal if the instances are the same (when you say `new Pair()` you're making a new instance!).

We can override this behavior by overriding the `equals()` method of your `Point` class. Like so:

```
public class Point {
    private final x;
    private final y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    private static boolean isPoint(Object o) {
        return o != null && o instanceof Point;
    }

    private boolean coordsEqual(Point p) {
        return getX() == p.getX() && getY() == p.getY();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return isPoint(o) && coordsEqual((Point) o); //is o is a point? Does it have equal coords?
    }
```

Now `Point.equals()` will return true if our coordinates match instead of the default object equals behavior. Since `Collection.contains()` uses the `equals()` method to check for equality, your code will behave as expected.

Comment: @SHIVANSH, consider up voting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write an `equals` method in your `Pair` class, so that the `List` can work out whether it contains the `Pair` that you're looking for.  The `List` will use your `equals` method when looking for matches.

The simplest way to write your `equals` method is to let your IDE generate it for you.

Comment: how can i get my IDE generate it . This is my first time on stackoverflow please be patient with me

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij Idea ultimate